# Selenium IDE - Format button greyed out

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

For some reason, when I go to export the sequence of actions I take with the Selenium IDE by going to Options -> Format, I see that Format is greyed out. I've restarted Firefox and looked online but have yet to find any explanations for what I'm seeing. A picture of what I've just described is linked below (can't yet post images- sorry).
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-xDzN9b8bPqs/TeblRvpeJ6I/AAAAAAAAAA4/McL3nJVcRTo/s512/selenium-ide-greyed.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format option has been turned OFF in the latest release. As per the release notes, Format changing is now marked as experimental due to possible issues, you can turn it on from the options dialog.

To turn it on, go to options->options and select 'enable experimental features'

[image]